# Tab markings in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, text-editor

In some of my text editors, there's a feature that draws vertical lines down the tab stops which makes it a breeze to ensure that braces are matched.

[image]

Does VS2010 have such a feature?

Comment: No, just a right margin.  How on Earth does that help?

Comment: A picture speaks a thousand words (or at least a couple of dozen). If a code block extends beyond a page's worth, it can be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AllMargins](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/465a0d53-5133-4edd-a0cd-94484fe3d853) VS2010 extension to get this functionality